# Autohotkey won't execute whole script

Tags: autohotkey

Here's my script:

```
^!m::Send hello
Sleep, 500
Send world
```

All it does, is sends "hello". How do I tell autohotkey to move forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're executing several lines you need to enclose them between the hotkey and a `return`.

Like so:

```
^!m::
    Send, hello
    Sleep, 500
    Send, world
return
```